# How to call jQuery function with an onclick link?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'd like the user to be able to remove an item from a list without having to reload the page, and am using jQuery/AJAX to do this.  However, with my current code the divs are not being removed.  I think I am traversing correctly, so not sure what the problem is.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BbpWc/1/

HTML:

```
<img src="delete.png" onclick="delete_item(<? echo $row_item['id'] ?>);">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    delete_item=function(item_id){
        var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this item?');
        if (confirmation){
            $.post(
               "../../items.php?id="+item_id+"&i=delete"
            )
            $(this).parent('.item_container').remove();
        }            
        else {
            return false;      
        }

    };  
})
```

Comment: You should use `$().click()` instead of inline-handlers. And you can store the `ID` in a `rel=""` or `data-` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BbpWc/9/

I have:

- Changed the anchors to spans
- Removed ID's in the current context, you don't need to have an ID in it.
- Removed onclick attribute and changed to jQuery click

Comment: I need to pass the ID along so that I can remove that item from the database.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was a little stupid of me :-) have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BbpWc/9/

Comment: In my case the elements are loaded by ajax so not available in DOM so had to do this instead: $(document).on("click",".removeModel",function(e)
        {
            var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this job?");
            if (confirmation)
            {
                $(this).closest('div.listing').hide('slow', function ()
                {
                    $(this).closest('div.listing').remove();
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        });

Answer (score 2):

You were missing parentheses on your call to `parent()`, and weren't passing in the DOM node from which you were traversing (the `$(this)` at the beginning of the jQuery selector), so given the updated jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    delete_item = function(item_id,that) {
        var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this item?');
        if (confirmation) {
            //$.post("../../items.php?id=" + item_id + "&i=delete")
            $(that).parent().prev().remove();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    };
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="item_container">
    Item 1
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="delete_item(1,this);">Delete 1</a>
</div>

<div class="item_container">
    Item 2
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="delete_item(2,this);">Delete 2</a>
</div>

<div class="item_container">
    Item 3
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="delete_item(3,this);">Delete 3</a>
</div>
```

It now seems to work: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BbpWc/2/).

---

**Edited** to use jQuery's `click()` event, instead of the intrusive in-line event handlers:

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        var i = $(this).index('a') + 1;
        delete_item(i,$(this));
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BbpWc/3/).

---

**Edited** to note that, sometimes, things can be a little easier than expected:

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().prev('div.item_container').remove().end().remove();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BbpWc/4/).

Although, admittedly, it's not as easily reusable as a function living in a library file somewhere...

---

**Edited** to in response to @roXon's comment (below) regarding the use of the `andSelf()` method:

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().prev('div.item_container').andSelf().remove();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BbpWc/6/).

Comment: Something about a variable function declared in a ready block and inline event handlers feels dirty. Also, I'm not sure that the AJAX request shouldn't use `$.get()` instead, since no POST variables appear to be sent. And... Shouldn't the removal of the element be done on `success` of the AJAX call, not before?

Comment: Probably, but without further input from the OP about what he wants I'll try to answer the explicit question to the best of my ability, if s/he wants to improve further then I'll happily explore those options. Also, ridiculously tired right now, so...yeah: I should've thought of that myself, really. And I heartily agree with mixture of in-line event handlers and variable functions...still: we've all gotta start learning somewhere =)

Comment: `$(this).parent().prev('div.item_container').andSelf().remove();`    (To not forget the `andSelf()` traversing method )

Comment: @roXon, thanks! I, uh, hadn't forgotten! Um...I was just...darn. You caught me! =) *edited in!*

Comment: Thanks for your help guys!  I need to pass the ID along however, so that the POST can remove the correct item from the database.